# How to verify that ordered Subnet was created?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When ordernig a subnet through (java) API, it is required to place a subnet order like this:

```
Receipt orderResult = com.softlayer.api.service.billing.Order.service(client).placeOrder(subnet, Boolean.FALSE);
```

The resulting Receipt object has order id populated, but there is no subnet id returned.

Is there a way to find out using the Softlayer API which subnet was created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subnetid can be found from:

`slcli subnet list`

Then it is possible to query to billing item associated with subnet:

`curl -g "https://[username]:<api-key>@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3//SoftLayer_Network_Subnet/<subnet_id>/getBillingItem`

This is goint to return a Softlayer_Billing_Item object with populated orderItemID.

And orderItem ID can be found when looking at Report object that was returned when creating a subnet.

If the orderID matches, the subnet was indeed created.